# Launch new activity, makes running animation slow

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to simulating shared element transition for lower android api based on a tutorial from [DevBytes: Custom Activity Animations](https://youtu.be/CPxkoe2MraA)

In main activity I'm using [Bottom Navigation](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) that can be hide and restore with animation. All things works fine.

the issue is when bottom navigation is going to get hide, new activity launched and cause new activity background is transparent, user can see the bottom navigation...
And the problem shows off itself here... animation ( slide out ) running so slowly and laggy.

It seems the issue related to launch new activity,
Really what happened to running animation when new activity launched?

Answer (score 0):

Use AnimationListener and start new activity in onAnimationEnd Method

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                                this, your_anim
                        );anim.setDuration(300);
                        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                nav.setVisibility(View.Gone);
                                startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this,Activity2.class));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                            }
                        });
                        nav.startAnimation(anim );
```

Answer (score 0):

use overridePendingTransition ,add this code on previous activity on click to open your new activity for animation;

`overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up,R.anim.stay);`

Comment: Hi, If you see the video tutorial, I've done it before